# Unable to add DOUBLE and VARCHAR columns with CAST()

Tags: mysql, sql, casting, int, varchar

I have two columns in my `billing` table:

- `cost_per_month`, `VARCHAR`
- `additional_cost`, `DOUBLE`

When I:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS("", "$", FORMAT(db.billing.cost_per_month, 2)) AS "Monthly Cost",
  CONCAT_WS("", "$", FORMAT(db.billing.additional_cost, 2)) AS "Additional Cost",
  CONCAT_WS("", "$", FORMAT(CAST(db.billing.cost_per_month AS DECIMAL(60, 2)) + db.billing.additional_cost, 2)) AS "Total Cost"
  FROM db.billing;
```

I get:

```
Monthly Cost  Additional Cost  Total Cost
$1,000.00     $                $
$0.00         $400.00          $400.00
$250.00       $250.00          $
```

Instead of:

```
Monthly Cost  Additional Cost  Total Cost
$1,000.00     $0.00            $1,000.00
$0.00         $400.00          $400.00
$250.00       $250.00          $500.00
```

I have tried:

- using `CAST(db.billing.cost_per_month AS SIGNED)`
- using `CAST(db.billing.cost_per_month AS UNSIGNED)`
- removing the `FORMAT()` and `CONCAT_WS()` functions
- using `SUM()` a bunch of different ways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is due to the `NULL` values that exist when there is no `cost_per_month` or `additional_cost` for a row.

A work around is to utilize `COALESCE()` instead of `CAST()`.

In your case:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS("", "$", FORMAT(COALESCE(db.billing.cost_per_month, 0.00), 2)) AS "Monthly Cost",
  CONCAT_WS("", "$", FORMAT(COALESCE(db.billing.additional_cost, 0.00),  2)) AS "Additional Cost",
  CONCAT_WS("", "$", FORMAT(COALESCE(db.billing.cost_per_month, 0.00) AS DECIMAL(60, 2)) + COALESCE(db.billing.additional_cost, 0.00), 2)) AS "Total Cost"
  FROM db.billing;
```

Comment: Ignore my last comment, you were 100% correct.  I must not have entered in everything correctly.  My apologies.